# How can i copy a row from one table into an other with a button click?

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable

I want to copy a selected DataTable-Row (left side) from one Table to another Table (right side) when the rightArrow-button is clicked.

[image]

How can I remember the selected row, after I clicked the rightArrow-button for the Event-Handler (Button_Click)?

I think, when I know the row, I can insert it with something like this: `dataTable2.Rows.Add(dataTable1.selectedRow)`

Comment: I see that the 2nd DataGrid looks different from the 1st. So you cannot proceed with `dataTable2.Rows.Add(dataTable1.selectedRow)`, because a column will be missing. You need to add a new object to the 2nd DataGrid, copying its details from the selected row of the 1st DataGrid.

Comment: I know it's already done sry for the bad picture.

Comment: Can you post the xaml of your datagrids pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The row will still be selected when it loses focus.
Either bind or use directly SelectedItem.
That will give you a datarowview.
That has a row property which you can use importrow on

```
        DataRow row = selectedDataRowView.Row;

        dataTable1.ImportRow(row);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for Help i did it on that way: `string[] data = new string[3]; DataRowView datarow = (DataRowView)dgAllData.SelectedItem; data[0] = (string) datarow.Row.ItemArray[0]; data[1] = (string) datarow.Row.ItemArray[1]; data[2] = (string) datarow.Row.ItemArray[2]; tableSelectedRow.Rows.Add(data[0], data[1], data[2])`